# TeXShop GUI in Dark Mode hard to read

Tags: texshop

I just installed TeXShop 4.44 on my Mac (running Mojave) and saw that the LaTeX button is really hard to read. I played around with the Preferences/Themes but was not able to set the font or the background to a lighter colour. Note that I *was* able to select LiteTheme for the editor, console, and output.

I attach a screenshot. The button in question is on the far left, under the semaphore. Is there any way to make the font lighter or the background lighter? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen those buttons used in a very long time. Ctl-Click (or Right-Click) in an space in the toolbar and choose `Customize Toolbar…`. Then remove those buttons and put in the Typeset button and Program Popdown List.

The best way to typeset a document is to use a declaration line to tell TeXShop what to use on a file by file basis: e.g.,

% !TEX program = pdflatex

at the top of a file tells TeXShop to typeset using pdflatex as the typesetting engine when you simply do Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T). Use `latex` instead of `pdflatex` above to use latex->dvips->ps2pdf when you use Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T). You can use any of the engines displayed in the Popdown List.

Comment: Great, thank you @Herb Schulz! Yes, I was familiar with the Customize Toolbar possibility but did not realise I could use the Typeset button. Duh Very visible now :)